# How can I scanf a string from the user in C with a do while loop using strlen()?

Tags: c

The code below doesn't work, it does not give me back the word I type in and in fact, it never stops asking for a string. Could you please explain to me how I can get a string from the user?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char word[20];

    do
    {
       scanf("%c", word);
    }
    while (strlen (word) > 0 && strlen (word) <20);

    printf("the word is %s", word);
}
```

Comment: `"%c"` => `"%s"`

Comment: read the manuel, please."c

Matches a sequence of characters whose length is specified by the maximum field width (default 1); the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters (no terminating null byte is added). The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed. To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the format."

Comment: @Broman `"%s"` => `"%19s"`

Answer (score -1):

`word` is *not* a c-string as it does not have a "NUL" terminator.

Doing `strlen` might invoke [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as `word` does not have a `\0`.

> Could you please explain to me how I can get a string from the user?

One way is to use the `fgets` function to read in strings easily.